# Use in Mathematica Symbolize for a concatenation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use as a symbol \xi^i_j and each time in my code a do a derivation I add an index (for example \xi^i_j -> \xi^i_j_k).

I know that i can use Symbolize in order to have the symbol \xi^i_j. But how to add an indices at each step automatically ? (The number of components increase by *4 at each step, I can't do it by hand...)

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use "\xi^i_j" <> "_k" in Symbolize but it doesn't work at all.

On top of that "\xi^i_j" <> "_k" give me an expression with a extra space "\xi^i_j _k".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special about the subscript notation in Mathematica. As far as the engine is concerned, the form you're describing ξ<sub>k</sub> is really just `Subscript[ξ, k]`. So if you have an arbitrary term `α` and you want to add a subscript to it (regardless of whether or not the term `α` already has a subscript), you can simply write

```
Subscript[α, k]
```

And the Mathematica engine will format it as a subscript, provided you're outputting in standard form.